# Why does the Slack integration notify of my own activity?

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-for-teams, slack

I'm using Stack Overflow for teams and I have installed the Slack integration. It's pretty helpful, but I'd like to avoid unnecessary noise. Why does it notify me in Slack about my own activity?

For example, if I ask a question or answer a question, the SO integration sends me a notification in Slack, "New activity in [our project]".

Can I disable notifications for my activity, but still get the notice about everything else?